# Julia DataFrame manipulation: concatenate datarow contents

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am trying to concatenate the contents of the rows of a DataFrame similar to this one:

```
DataFrame(a=["aa","ab","ac"], year=[2015,2016,2017])

a       year
aa      2015 
ab      2016 
ac      2017
```

The desired output would be a concatenation of the contents of the row cells converted to string

```
output
aa2015
ab2016
ac2017
```

I have found this code working in the right direction:

```
df[:c] = map((x,y) -> string(x, y), df[:a], df[:year])
```

However my input can be variable as I can have a different number of columns and I want all their contents to be concatenated row by row.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this? It doesn't matter if the column gets added to the original Dataframe, if that helps.

Thanks a lot

Comment: It is safer to write `df.c` than `df[:c]` as the latter pattern might get deprecated in the future.

Comment: good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `eachrow` to achieve this:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(rand('a':'z', 5,5))
5×5 DataFrame
│ Row │ x1   │ x2   │ x3   │ x4   │ x5   │
│     │ Char │ Char │ Char │ Char │ Char │
├─────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
│ 1   │ 'l'  │ 'p'  │ 'y'  │ 't'  │ 'n'  │
│ 2   │ 'p'  │ 'y'  │ 'y'  │ 'r'  │ 's'  │
│ 3   │ 'y'  │ 'a'  │ 'o'  │ 'c'  │ 'a'  │
│ 4   │ 'k'  │ 't'  │ 'q'  │ 's'  │ 'q'  │
│ 5   │ 'a'  │ 'c'  │ 'w'  │ 'f'  │ 'v'  │

julia> join.(eachrow(df))
5-element Array{String,1}:
 "lpytn"
 "pyyrs"
 "yaoca"
 "ktqsq"
 "acwfv"
```

(here I just created a new vector - you can of course add it to a `DataFrame` if you want)

Comment: woah that was fast :) can you just please help me out on how to do the last conversion? Junior here... :D

Comment: What "last conversion" do you mean? To add the vector to a `DataFrame` as column `all` just write `df.all = join.(eachrow(df))`.